# Radiation collapse to black hole

Tags: general-relativity, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, thermal-radiation, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

I want to find the temperature at which radiation in AdS will collapse to form a black hole. I have even found a reference that gives the answer but I cannot understand it: http://srv2.fis.puc.cl/~mbanados/Cursos/TopicosRelatividadAvanzada/HawkingPage.pdf

In eqn 3.3 he claims the radiation will collapse at a temperature $T \sim g^{-1/4} m_p^{1/2} b^{-1/2}$ where $b$ is the AdS radius and $g$ is the number of spin states (see p579).

Question 1: Can $g$ be set to 1 in natural units?

Question 2: He says above (3.3) that this estimate for $T$ has been obtained by guessing $M \sim \mathcal{O}(m_p^2b)$. How can I see this?

Thanks.